# Does the WTO have a mechanism to accommodate states transitioning trade regimes?

Tags: international-trade

If the UK were to leave the EU without a Withdrawal Agreement in place it defaults to WTO trading terms.

Does the WTO have a mechanism to accommodate such a transition?